# `gather` can't handle rownames

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, tidyverse

```
allcsvs = list.files(pattern = "*.csv$", recursive = TRUE)

library(tidyverse)

##LOOP to redact the snow data csvs##
for(x in 1:length(allcsvs)) {
  df = read.csv(allcsvs[x], check.names = FALSE)

  newdf = df %>%
    gather(COL_DATE, SNOW_DEPTH, -PT_ID, -DATE) %>%
    mutate( 
      DATE = as.Date(DATE,format = "%m/%d/%Y"),
      COL_DATE = as.Date(COL_DATE, format = "%Y.%m.%d")
    ) %>%
    filter(DATE == COL_DATE) %>%
    select(-COL_DATE)

  ####TURN DATES UNAMBIGUOUS HERE####
  df$DATE = lubridate::mdy(df$DATE)
  finaldf = merge(newdf, df, all.y = TRUE)
  write.csv(finaldf, allcsvs[x])

  df = read.csv(allcsvs[x])
  newdf = df[, -grep("X20", colnames(df))]
  write.csv(newdf, allcsvs[x])
}
```

I am using the code above to populate a new column row-by-row using values from different existing columns, using date as selection criteria. If I manually open each .csv in excel and delete the first column, this code works great. However, if I run it on the .csvs "as is"

I get the following message:

`Error: Column 1 must be named`

So far I've tried putting `-rownames` within the parenthesis of `gather`, I've tried putting `remove_rownames %>%` below `newdf = df %>%`, but nothing seems to work. I tried reading the csv without the first column `[,-1]` or deleting the first column in R `df[,1]<-NULL` but for some reason when I do that my code returns an empty table instead of what I want it to. **In other words, I can delete the rownames in Excel and it works great, if I delete them in R something funky happens.**

Here is some sample data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RiMrx4wOpUdJkN4il6IopciSF6pKeNLr/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want `row.names = 1` in `read.csv`? Although it's a bit confusing because your code seems to reference column names that aren't in your example data.

Comment: @joran yes I've tried that. It's a very sneaky bug. My code does reference columns that don't exist. We are defining two variables `COL_DATE` and `SNOW_DEPTH`. Technically, the date columns aren't technically valid column names, but we are moving them from column names to variables..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider to import them with `readr::read_csv`.

An easy solution with `tidyverse`:

```
allcsvs %>%
            map(read_csv) %>% 
            reduce(bind_rows) %>%
            gather(COL_DATE, SNOW_DEPTH, -PT_ID, -DATE) %>% 
            mutate( 
                            DATE = as.Date(DATE,format = "%m/%d/%Y"),
                            COL_DATE = as.Date(COL_DATE, format = "%Y.%m.%d")
            ) %>%
            filter(DATE == COL_DATE) %>%
            select(-COL_DATE)
```

With `utils::read.csv`, you are importing strings are factors. `as.Date(DATE,format = "%m/%d/%Y")` evaluates `NA`.

**Update**

Above solution returns one single dataframe. To write the each data file separately with the for loop:

```
for(x in 1:length(allcsvs)) {
  read_csv(allcsvs[x]) %>% 
    gather(COL_DATE, SNOW_DEPTH, -PT_ID, -DATE) %>% 
    mutate( 
      COL_DATE = as.Date(COL_DATE, format = "%Y.%m.%d")
    ) %>%
    filter(DATE == COL_DATE) %>%
    select(-COL_DATE) %>%
    write_csv(paste('tidy', allcsvs[x], sep = '_'))
}
```

**Comparison**

- `purrr:map` and `purrr:reduce` can be used instead of for loop in some cases. Those functions take another functions as arguments.
- `readr::read_csv` is typically 10x faster than base R equivalents. (More info: http://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-import.html). Also it can handle CSV files better.