# Gather using rownames

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm forecasting time-series data (which uses row names) and would like to combine some accuracy measures into a single data frame whilst distinguishing between methods. As an example:

```
library(fpp2)
beer.train <- window(beer, end = c(1994, 12))
beer.test <- window(beer, start = 1995)
AccMean <- accuracy(meanf(beer.train, h = 8), beer.test)
AccRW <- accuracy(rwf(beer.train, h = 8), beer.test)
rbind(AccMean, AccRW)
#                         ME     RMSE      MAE         MPE     MAPE     MASE       ACF1 Theil's U
# Training set -9.474373e-15 19.82001 15.97396  -1.6202496 10.42125 1.726914  0.4628439        NA
# Test set     -1.289583e+01 17.57100 13.57292 -10.1596449 10.60310 1.467342 -0.4904015 0.7998411
# Training set  3.829787e-01 20.18004 15.14894  -0.6398801 10.05885 1.637723 -0.1547700        NA
# Test set     -4.375000e+01 45.34865 43.75000 -32.6470928 32.64709 4.729730 -0.4904015 2.0312792
```

However, I'd like to see output like:

```
# Method   Set            ME     RMSE      MAE         MPE     MAPE     MASE       ACF1 Theil's U
#   Mean Train -9.474373e-15 19.82001 15.97396  -1.6202496 10.42125 1.726914  0.4628439        NA
#   Mean  Test -1.289583e+01 17.57100 13.57292 -10.1596449 10.60310 1.467342 -0.4904015 0.7998411
#     RW Train  3.829787e-01 20.18004 15.14894  -0.6398801 10.05885 1.637723 -0.1547700        NA
#     RW  Test -4.375000e+01 45.34865 43.75000 -32.6470928 32.64709 4.729730 -0.4904015 2.0312792
```

One way would be to do the following:

```
AccMean <- AccMean %>% as.data.frame() %>% mutate(Method = "Mean", Set = c("Train", "Test")) %>% select(Method, Set, everything())
AccRW <- AccRW %>% as.data.frame() %>% mutate(Method = "RW", Set = c("Train", "Test")) %>% select(Method, Set, everything())
rbind(AccRW, AccMean)
#   Method   Set            ME     RMSE      MAE         MPE     MAPE     MASE       ACF1 Theil's U
# 1   Mean Train -9.474373e-15 19.82001 15.97396  -1.6202496 10.42125 1.726914  0.4628439        NA
# 2   Mean  Test -1.289583e+01 17.57100 13.57292 -10.1596449 10.60310 1.467342 -0.4904015 0.7998411
# 3     RW Train  3.829787e-01 20.18004 15.14894  -0.6398801 10.05885 1.637723 -0.1547700        NA
# 4     RW  Test -4.375000e+01 45.34865 43.75000 -32.6470928 32.64709 4.729730 -0.4904015 2.0312792
```

however I'd like to generalise this to `n` methods, and the above would be tedious for large `n`. I imagine using `gather()` would be helpful but I can't seem to get it to work with `row.names`.

Note that [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50513303/gather-cant-handle-rownames) does not answer mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily done using `purrr`'s `imap` function.

The first trick is to pre-define all your test method *functions* and labeling them:

```
# define and label test methods
test_methods <- list(
  Mean = meanf,
  RW = rwf
)
```

Then, we let `imap_dfr` do the fun stuff - applying each function to the data, reformatting it, labeling it, and binding it all together

```
library(purrr)
result_df <- imap_dfr(test_methods, function(f, .method) {
  tmp <- accuracy(f(beer.train, h = 8), beer.test) 
  tmp %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    mutate(
      Set = str_extract(rownames(tmp), "Train|Test"),
      Method = .method
    ) %>% 
    select(Method, Set, everything())
})
```

We use `imap` because it automatically sets the 2nd variable in the function (here `.method`) to the names in our list (e.g. the names in `test_methods`).  It's exactly what is needed here.

### Update

To add arguments to the function calls, we need to incorporate that information into the test methods.  For example:

```
test_methods <- list(
  Mean = meanf,
  RW = rwf,
  RWdrift = function(x, ...) rwf(x, drift = TRUE, ...)
)
```

The dot notation is needed because `h=8` is hard coded into into the function calls.  If `h` varies too, you need to remove it from the call within the `imap_dfr`, and specify it in all `test_methods` entries:

```
test_methods <- list(
  Mean08 = function(x) meanf(x, h = 8),
  Mean10 = function(x) meanf(x, h = 10),
  RW8 = function(x) rwf(x, h = 8,
  RWdrift8 = function(x, ...) rwf(x, h = 8, drift = TRUE, ...)
)
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks! How would this extend to functions with additional arguments? For example, using `rwf(beer.train, h = 8, drift = TRUE)`.